# How do I install novo-builder?

Tags: bash, 14.10

Recently,I want make a Ubuntu live CD. However I don't know how to install novo-builder. The document is Install_Novo_Builder.bash. Please tell me how to install novo-builder using bash.

Answer (score 0):

`Install_Novo_Builder.bash` is the filename of the script you need to execute. So make the file executable and execute it.

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar xvf Install_Novo_Builder.tar.gz 
chmod 775 Install_Novo_Builder.bash
./Install_Novo_Builder.bash
```

- the tar will extract the `Install_Novo_Builder.bash` file.

---

By the way... the script executes a normal "get key, add PPA, update and install package":

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$UID" -ne "0" ]
then
   gksudo -k -u root bash $0
fi

if [ "$UID" -ne "0" ]
then
   exit
fi

wget -O - http://www.cyvoc.net/novo-repo/Cyvoc.key | apt-key add -
echo deb http://www.cyvoc.net/novo-repo stable main non-free > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cyvoc.list

apt-get update

apt-get install novo-builder novo-preset-lastos
```

so if you want to do this yourself execute the 4 lines from `wget` to the bottom.

Comment: Amazing!^-^. Thank you. You help me solve a big problem.

Comment: I would create the live dvd manually though @CorenX  This will help you on your way: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd